# Does Asus H87M-E support 2 graphic cards?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I am looking at the specs of this motherboard http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H87ME/specifications/ and I am not sure if it supports 2 graphic cards or not.

I need to run them one by another, not in SLI.

Here is its image from the official site

[image]

What do you say?

Comment: Hopefully it doesn't i think.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure if it supports 2 graphic cards or not.

If you can find a PCI-e x1 graphics board then it would work.  The motherboard you are asking about only has a single PCI-E 3.0 x 16 slot.  You could in theory convert the PCI-E x1 slot to a PCI-E x16 slot if you wanted.  If you want the performance from having to PCI-e x16 cards that would require a different motherboard though.

1. [PCI-E Extension Cable 1X To 16X Slot Riser Extender Card Flex Cable Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C7FRDXI)
2. [PCI Express X1 to X16 Low Profile Slot Extension Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0039XPS5W)

You can also use

> 1 x PCIe 3.0/2.0 x16 (x16 mode, yellow)
>
> 3 x PCIe 2.0 x1

[Source](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/H87ME/specifications/)

Comment: Well, they're easy to find, but only the low profile mode.